# How to set up my constraint perfectly to the bottom in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I am using `AutoLayout` in Storyboard. I have set `translateAutoResizingMasksToConstraints` to false. I have created a constraint like so:

[image]

The `superView` takes up the whole screen's `frame`. When I run the App, the `bottom bar view` doesn't appear. However, if in the picture I change `constant` to `50`, it jumps up to about where it should be expected.

I have had a previous branch where I did not set it to `50` but due to some other `constraints` it appeared as expected. But it's not exact and I don't know why it's behaving this way all of a sudden. I've used the `View Debugger` feature and the `bottom bar view` straight up doesn't appear at all.

How can I set it so that the `constraint` has a `constant` of `0` and still appears? What might be a reason for this bug? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Will be needing more information regarding your view hierarchy and other constraints.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to add constraints to two items, you try an easier way by choosing two of them(even super view) like this:

[image]

Then click 'add new constraints' on the right bottom of storyboard/xib,

[image]

Then you can choose different types of align constraints as you like.
If you only choose one item to add new constraint, then align will be disabled cause it needs two items.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aligning to the superview each time and the method you mention

Comment: Glad my answer can help. Would you mind choosing my answer as the one you prefer if it is helpful to you?

Comment: Sorry what I meant was that I was already doing what the answer said.

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the bar's frame in view did appear, if you are not sure whether the bar is just outside the visible field. Have you set constraints to the sides and a height as well? As a rule of thumb you can say that a view needs 4 constraints before iOS knows exactly where you meant for the view to be placed.

Comment: Hi, in IB it does not allow me to change the parent constraints. Wehn I change the background color, the whole screen gets colored

Comment: Not sure what you are saying? I assume that the bottom bar is your view? Which view are you changing the background on? Perhaps a screenshot of your view hierarchy in IB could clear up a lot

Comment: I have now. Thanks for the debugging tips